# Delphi - open next file from a list once procedure finishes on the first

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a total of **3214** .`doc`. I need to open the first file, copy its contents, paste it in a `RichEdit`, extract some text, insert it into a database then move on to the next file and repeat the procedure.

So far I've managed to:

- Open the 1st .doc/any 1 .doc only
- Copy the content and paste it in the RichEdit
- Extract the text from the RichEdit
- Insert the extracted text into the database
- Close the opened .doc and clear the content of RichEdit

I've loaded all 3214 filenames, in order, into a `Memo`.

Once I finish with the 1st file from the list, how do I now make it move to the next .doc from the list and do the same thing, repeating this till I finish all the 3214 .doc files? Currently reading about loops but I can't figure it out yet.

Code so far:

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  content: string;
  StartPos: Integer;
  endPos: Integer;
  i: integer;
  fname: string;
  WordApp : Variant;    
begin
  WordApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  for i := 1 to 1 do    
    fname := Memo1.Lines[i - 1];
  WordApp.Visible := True;
  WordApp.Documents.Open('C:\Users\tcsh\Desktop\all\'+fname);
  WordApp.ActiveDocument.Select;
  WordApp.Selection.Copy;
  RichEdit1.Lines.Add(WordApp.Selection);
  WordApp.documents.item(1).Close;
  WordApp.Quit;

  content:= RichEdit1.Text;    
  //<text extract code is here>    
  begin
    //<sql code is here>
  end;

  RichEdit1.Clear;
  Edit1.Clear;
  Edit2.Clear;
  Edit3.Clear;
  Edit4.Clear;
  Edit5.Clear;
  Edit7.Clear;
  Edit8.Clear;
  //the TEdit's hold the extracted text so the sql can retrieve it from them and insert into the database
end;
```

Comment: You need to study more syntax first. Start with using BEGIN...END for loops. Currently only the line `fname := Memo1.Lines[i - 1];` in in the loop, the rest is only executed ONCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i := 1 to 1 do
```

Hmmm, that *will* only run once..

You may also want to try:

- Create the WordApp object in each iteration ,
- Add a time delay in between each iteration (using Sleep and Application.ProcessMessages) (as LU RD points out this is not necessary)

Code sample below:

```
  for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
    WordApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
    fname := Memo1.Lines[i];
    WordApp.Visible := True;
    WordApp.Documents.Open(fname);
    WordApp.ActiveDocument.Select;
    WordApp.Selection.Copy;
    Memo2.Lines.Add(WordApp.Selection);
    Memo2.Lines.Add('===');
    WordApp.documents.item(1).Close;
    WordApp.Quit;
    //Sleep(1000);  -> not needed
    //Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
```

Comment: `Sleep` and `Application.ProcessMessages` does not belong to here. To what purpose is that justified?

Comment: @LU RD: You are quite right - it is not needed. The main thing is to include `CreateOleObject` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with [System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles)

```
GetFiles('C:\temp\', '*.doc');
```

Here is an [example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/DirectoriesAndFilesEnumeraion_(Delphi))

You'll find a few here on SO.

***Update***

```
...
var
line: string;
...   
for line in Memo1.Lines do begin
 <your code per file>
 ShowMessage(line);
end
```

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: This is another question. Which line exactly?

Comment: *..and then it moves to the second FILE..* - That's what you asked: *"..how do I now make it move to the next .doc from the list.."*. --- *"..and throws the error there.*" - That's not what you asked.